# Easiest way to wrap a canvas tag + javascript in a Python program?

Tags: javascript, python, html, cocos2d-iphone, cross-platform

I'm creating a cross-platform game using cocos2d-javascript and would like to create a PC version that looks native. I understand that with little modification, I can have my cocos2d-javascript program run in a browser, but I'd like to have the program run in its own (non-browser) window, be able to create multiple windows, have native access to the filesystem without going through browser security controls, etc. Essentially, I'd like to have my Python program provide a javascript engine along with a canvas tag that cocos2d-html5 could run on. A very stripped down browser, if you will.

My question is, what's the simplest way to accomplish this, in a cross-platform (i.e. PC, Mac, and Linux) manner? I can use python-spidermonkey or python-v8 for the javascript engine, but I'm unsure how best to provide a canvas tag that can be drawn on.

Comment: If you're starting from scratch, obviously just simulating an HTML canvas will be a lot simpler than simulating an entire HTML DOM. But if you're looking for pre-existing code that does it, I don't know of anything that does the former, and there are multiple possibilities for the latter. The obvious is WebKit/Chromium, and there are a few different wrappers for that. Is that what you want?

Comment: hmm, yes, I am looking for simplest in terms of "least code for me to write". I would also need to be able to hook from the JS code into python code (in the same places those hooks would be into native Objective-C code, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the simplest in terms of "least code for me to write", it's actually easier to embed a full browser, than to write a stripped-down browser from scratch.

So, the simplest solution is probably to use a [`QWebView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html).

Under the covers, this is about as far from simple (or "stripped-down") as you can get: you're using a powerful, complicated cross-platform GUI library that has a deeply-integrated WebKit wrapper that exposes custom objects for things like URLs and even web pages all the way up to the object model.

But from your code, it's just a matter of sticking a web view into a window, creating an HTML page with a `canvas` tag and your JS app, and hooking everything up.

One downside is the learning curve. Qt is big, and you're going to have to learn at least the basic concepts before you can do anything useful. Fortunately, if you've done ObjC programming, signals-and-slots, the QObject model, etc. should all feel pretty familiar… but not exactly the same.

The other downside is distribution. You either need to require Qt and PySide (or PyQt) along with Python (which is a heavy requirement, unless you only care about linux users), or learn the ins and outs of packaging `PySide` up with `cx_freeze`/`py2exe`/`py2app`/etc.

---

Talking to the canvas or the JS code from outside is ridiculously easy. The `QWebView` contains a `QWebPage`, which contains a `QWebFrame`, which is a complete DOM made up of `QWebElement` wrappers:

```
frame = view.page().mainFrame()
canvas = frame.findFirstElement("#cocos-canvas')
```

You can then call `evaluateJavaScript` on the DOM itself or on any of the elements, in the same way you find familiar from ObjC's WebKit wrapper.

For going the other way, while you *can* do the same tricks of injecting JS or evaluating function definitions that call back to your code, you can also just attach `QAction`s to a web page, which you can then hook up the same way you do with normal actions (menu items, button clicks, etc.). And of course JS can trigger them just as easily as a user can.

Or you can expose any `QObject` subclass directly to JS by calling [`addToJavaScriptWindow`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject), which allows your JS code to call methods on the object, including methods that attach callbacks. See [The QtWebKit Bridge](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html) for details.

Comment: +1 for the tip on which library to use. But, would I be able to communicate between the webview's javascript engine & my python code w/ this solution?

Comment: @Claudiu: Yes. You can do the same kind of inject-and-eval-JS that it sounds like you're used to from… iOS maybe? But even simpler, you can assign `QAction`s directly to web DOM elements, which can be triggered by JS just as easily as by a user with a mouse. See the examples on the linked page. (Unfortunately, they're C++ rather than Python, but if you write ObjC, JS, and Python, I'm guessing you can at least read C++.) If you need a more detailed/specific example I can hunt one down.

Comment: Hmm looks promising indeed! I'll do a bit of poking around on the site but this might be the way to go. It's either this, or re-implement the graphics engine in pygame or something for the PC version, but this seems easier.

Comment: re: Your latest edit, either way I would use python, so the only question is how much bigger Qt & PyQt would be vs. just pygame, for example. I've actually used a bit of Qt in a project before, which should make using it again a bit easier!

Comment: @Claudiu: It's definitely bigger, and more painful to package up. PySide makes the latter a little nicer (as well as improving some licensing problems), but not the former. Looking at a PyQt app and a pygame app I have lying around on my Mac, the former has 15.9MB of PyQt+Qt out of 24MB total, while the latter is 3.4MB total… Still, I have yet to find anything nearly as nice as Qt for web<->native interaction, short of writing the native code as a local web/WebSockets service (which is, actually, another useful possibility).